# Java - is superclass executed while running subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I have two java class, One is Super class and other is a base class. It means base class inherits the supeclass. I am able to understand this concept. My Doubt is "If I am executing or running the base class ALONE, Does the Superclass be executed ? ".

I want to know whether the Super class is executed or not, if I only execute baseclass.

Comment: Classes do **not** run. You invoke **methods**; and for those, there are  **well documented** rules how polymorphism kicks in.

Comment: I think you have a false concept of object orientation. Classes (or rather objects) don't get "executed". You can call methods on objects or set attributes. And furthermore "while running..." implies that you think there is some kind of parallelism.

Comment: During instantiation (calling the new ...) the default (no args) constructor of base class is called, if there's no default constructor or you want to use another one you need to call explicitly the parent constructor using super() as first statement in constructor of your child class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I learnt from your comments

Answer (score 0):

read https://www.sitepoint.com/interface-and-inheritance-in-java-inheritance/

baseclass is also the superclass that you think. Inheritance means that child already have the all attributes/properties/methods_and_variables that the parents have if they are in the same package. Child can do anything that he can do and what the parent can do by inheriting it. Therefore parent don't need to run anymore because child already know what the parent can do.

If you execute the parent, child is not executed and parent don't have the child attributes.
If you execute the child with inheritance to parent. The child is executed with parents attribute but the parent itself is not.

Answer (score 0):

During instantiation (calling the new ...) the default (no args) constructor of base class is called, if there's no default constructor or you want to use another one you need to call explicitly the parent constructor using super() as first statement in constructor of your child class. Also non-static initialization blocks are called as well as variables instantation. This is something that can be named as "running the parent class". There is also static initailization - static initaialization blocks and static variables initialization, that are run before the class is first used.